# Why has Xdebug detected a possible infinite loop?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I wanted to share my problem that I faced and I will comment out the answer that I found to help with this issue:
I replaced jwt-auth with sanctum then after finishing setting up the existing project from another developer I faced this error :
`Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames laravel sanctum`

I added this line of code in `bootstrap/autoload.php` :

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 10000);
```

and it didn't work either and kept changing the stack depth value to any value I'm giving and stuck in an infinite loop in logs.

---

The solution was as simple as possible which is :

adding `accept : application\json` in the header because sanctum can not work without it

but here is the thing, it did not solve it it just hide it as it got caught in the error handler, I'll update once I solve it.

**Solution** :

I found a line of code called "guard : api" in sanctum.php, when I removed it it worked and got out of the loop.

Comment: please dont add answers, edit your question to add details (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you share the code responsible of the error and not the symptoms. What code is causing the infinite loop ?

Comment: @N69S I apologize, I have no idea what is the cause till now ...

Comment: you said "it got caught in the error handler", The handler must have shown a message with a backtrace ? check also the logs files. if you have a script line where the error happens, add the code around it to your question